# Find similar records by tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have one `MySQL` table with one `'name'` field and 7 tag text-fields `(tag1, tag2, ...)`.

Not all 7 tag fields need to be filled, some records have only 3 or 4 tags.

Tags are not alphabetically ordered in anyway.

I need to select one record an then list 10 other records with similar tags. Records with the same 7 tags (if there is some) should appear before the ones with 6 similar tags, and so on.

Maybe would it be better to split the table?

Comment: What's the criteria of selecting the first record? Better post sample input output.

Comment: Please post code you are having specific problems with. We can't do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished utilizing `FIND_IN_SET` to producing a matching order rank.

Try this:

```
(select * from t1 where name = 'input_name')
union all
(select from t2.name, t2.tag1, t2.tag2, t2.tag3, t2.tag4, t2.tag5, t2.tag6, t2.tag7 
(
    select
        *,
        FIND_IN_SET(tag1, @tags) + FIND_IN_SET(tag2, @tags) + FIND_IN_SET(tag3, @tags) + FIND_IN_SET(tag4, @tags) +
        FIND_IN_SET(tag5, @tags) + FIND_IN_SET(tag6, @tags) + FIND_IN_SET(tag7, @tags) AS cnt_tags
    from t1 CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT @tags := (select CONCAT_WS(',',tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7) 
                      from t1 where name = 'input_name')) param
) t2
where name != 'input_name'
order by cnt_tags desc 
limit 10)
```

> To use on your real table, replace `'input_name'` to your real filter `name`.